# Emacs & DSVN: change default commit message

Tags: svn, emacs, elisp

I am currently using DSVN in emacs 24.1.50.1 on OSX, with svn v 1.7.8.

When I run svn-status from emacs, mark several files and press 'c' to commit I find myself in the *svn commit* buffer that is pre-filled with the following:

```
Summary:
Author:
```

I have a different convention that I would like to follow, how can I change this default commit message?

I've looked through the source for svn-commit but I don't see where this message is coming from. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088286/moving-the-emacs-point-to-beginning-of-specific-text-for-perforce-commit-message) thread seems relevant but I'm not sure what hooks I might use to leverage the information presented there.

Ideally I would like to be able to determine the message dynamically based on the repository url for the current project, but even just a hint for how to change the message to something static would be great. How might I go about changing this message?

All help appreciated.

Comment: These headers are used by Emacs's code directly: the "Summary:" is placed as the first line of the commit, and the "Author:" is passed to the VCS according to how that VCS uses the author information.  If any of those headers is empty it's removed anyway.

Comment: I think newer emacsen changed something here, I had to `(remove-hook 'log-edit-hook #'log-edit-insert-message-template)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot locate the source in your emacs package, chances are this template comes from svn itself.

Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212640/can-we-change-the-default-svn-commit-template-using-svn-hooks), you can do a quick test to check if this would be the case for you.

If so, you could use `setenv` from emacs to recreate the trick described there, or defadvice `svn-commit` to replace the buffer contents with your own template, as you prefer (the later solution would work even if the template was not coming from svn)

Comment: I read that answer but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "do a quick check to see if this would be the case for you". I'd prefer a solution that stays within emacs, that way I can carry it around with the rest of my emacs profile. I wasn't aware of defadvice, I think that might be what I'm looking for - I'll give it a shot and see.

Comment: `defadvice` would be my choice (using a hook will be even better, but it seems there is none available).  The setenv SVN_EDITOR trick would be more useful to somebody with no elisp interest/skills.  By "quick check" I meant to find out if the origin of the template you are seeing is coming from emacs or from svn (again, with defadvice that is irrelevant)

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks! I will post anything I come up

Answer (score 0):

Based on juanleon's suggestion to use defadvice, here is some advice that will replace the contents of the *svn commit* buffer with a static message:

```
(defadvice svn-commit (after modify-default-commit-message activate) 
  (erasebuffer)
  (insert "custom message"))
```

This assumes that the buffer containing the commit message is selected after running svn-commit (in my case *svn-commit*).

A more dynamic version that invokes "svn info" and replaces the commit message with a regex-extracted value is:

```
(defadvice svn-commit (after modify-default-commit-message activate) 
  (erase-buffer)  
  (let ((svninfo (shell-command-to-string "svn info")))
    (string-match "^URL: svn://\\(.+\\)" svninfo)   
    (insert (match-string 1 svninfo))                                          
    (insert ": ")      
    ))
```

This advice will replace the commit message with the host and path of the svn url, followed by ": ", so if svn-commit is run from a checkout with url "svn://host.com/path" the commit message will be "host.com/path: ". If the regex fails the commit message will simply be empty.